# Extracting data from CDATA using LINQ to XML

Tags: linq-to-xml, cdata

I have the following xml file and I am trying to use linq to xml to get the Elements which are residing inside the CDATA section. Any suggestions please.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<result final = "true" transaction-id="84WO" xmlns="http://cp.com/rules/client">
<client id = "CustName'>
<quoteback>
</client>
<report format = "CP XML">
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "yes"?>
 <personal_auto xmlns = "http://cp.com/rules/client">
    <admin>
    </admin>
    <report>
    </report>
 </personal_auto>
]]>
</report> </result>
```

Comment: Please edit your question (and this time use a preview) as I don't see anything in your XML sample.

Comment: Your XML is invalid. The `<?xml` line must be the first line.

Comment: Still missing closingg `restult` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 XElement XTemp = XElement.Load(YourXMLfile);  
var queryCDATAXML = from element in XTemp.DescendantNodes()
                         where element.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.CDATA
                         select element.Parent.Value.Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is standard LINQ functionality - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcdata.aspx

Could you please explain the problem in more detail if this doesn't solve it?

Comment: My requirement is to get all the elements inside the CDATA section how can i get it using LINQ to XML

Comment: Ah, you want someone to do your job for you. Not actually answer a question. Right. One quick Google later: http://www.jarvis.com.au/post/2008/09/I-love-Linq-to-XML.aspx

Comment: Rushyo. sorry. My XML file has an XML file inside CDATA section.  The task that I am trying to achieve here is that I need to be able to navigate the xml file inside CDATA section and extract the necessary elements. any suggestions please?

Comment: Right. So what you're saying is you have an XML document inside an XML document? All within a LINQ statement? Not sure that's possible, though I'd be happy for someone to correct me. Generally speaking, I can't imagine someone doing that.

Comment: I'd suggest just grabbing the CDATA element you want, loading the document, then executing a second query on it.

Comment: Thats right. How can I extract <personal_auto> which is inside CDATA section using LINQ to XML.

Comment: I have come up with the following code                           var query = from element in xdoc.Root.DescendantNodesAndSelf()     where element.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.CDATA
   let textElement = element as XText
   select textElement.Value;
                                                                      foreach (var item in query)
      {
          XElement a = XElement.Parse(item);
      }                                                            Is there a better way to acheive the same?                                Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do something slightly different - I'm embedding sql in xml using cdata in its own dedicated element named 'sql'

Just to clarify cdata content will be read transparently.

if you do

```
var cdataContent = sql.Value;
```

you get whatever string is in the

```
 <![CDATA[..]]>
```

tag without having to instantiate a different node type on top of it or do anything fancy

so in the above case cdataContent would just be "..".

Linq to sql really is nice!  I always expect there to be more messing about involved.  Hats off to the guys who made that API.